# Windows phone 7 Media Element wav pause

Tags: windows-phone-7, wav, mediaelement

I'm recording sound from microphone. Then I save PCM with wav header to isolated storage. Afterwards I play it using MediaElement. I want to have ability to pause the song but it's seems to be impossible. I've tried to use SmoothStreamingMediaElement but the problem was the same - maybe I did something wrong.

If anybody has any idea how to pause the song from microhone then please help.

Here is my code but pause doesn't work. Maybe I can read the file different way?

```
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var audio = store.OpenFile(_song_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    _media_element.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(_media_element_MediaOpened);
                    _media_element.SetSource(audio);
                    audio.Close();
                }
            }
```

Pausing code is quite simple :)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _media_element.Pause();
    }
```

For testing I have made simple project with ability to downloading files from web and playing it from isolated storage. It works with wmv and mp3 but not with wav. Here is VS project [DowloadingAndPlayingWav](http://mjankowski.org/temp/wavTest.rar)

If anybody has any idea pleas help. I've hacked probably entire internet - there is no solution for this problem.

Comment: I suspect that there may be something wrong going on with your MediaStreamSource. I've been able to play/pause PCM audio from a custom MediaStreamSource on WP7 without any problems. Can you provide more code that shows when/how you are calling Pause()?

Comment: Can you give sample code? How you have made it?

Answer (score 0):

`MediaElement` has a [`Pause`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.pause%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method. Have you tried using that?

Comment: Yes but for streams it doesn't work - that's what documentation say. The same is for setting Position.

Comment: @Michal The documentation says it will fail silently when playing live streamING content, not when played from a file stream. Have you tried this?

Comment: Ok you right. However it still doesn't work with wav files, why? wmv -works, mp3 - works, wav - NOT! I've tried with 5 different wav files. The mediaElement1.CanPause returns "puseFalse" all the time!

Comment: @Michal if you get the saved file off the phone does it play with the ability to pause on a PC? Have you checked the capabilities of the saved Wav (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=vs.92).aspx)

Comment: I've red this page before, but it tells me not much. I don't know what is the "LPCM", "MS ADPCM" and so on. However I have checked following wav file: 6000Hz, 8Bit and it doesn't work. For testing I have made simple project with ability to downloading files from web and playing it from isolated storage. It works with wmv and mp3 but not with wav. Here is VS project http://mjankowski.org/temp/wavTest.rar

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested in this topic (from a search perhaps) I thought I'd share how I handled this in my app (Rapid Recorder).

I couldn't find a proper way to pause but it can easily be faked. When the pause button is clicked you just store the current playback position and you stop the playback. When the play button is pressed you just you can then just set your position again after you start playback. Here are some snippets:

```
private TimeSpan _pausedPosition;
```

To pause:

```
_pausedPosition = Player.Position;
Player.Stop();
```

To play:

```
Player.Play();
if (_pausedPosition != TimeSpan.Zero) Player.Position = _pausedPosition;
```